# why mysql can using index condition for two sinle column index?

Tags: mysql

I have one table as below

```
create table student (
id integer not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20) not null default '',
age integer not null default 0,
create_time datetime not null default '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
primary key (id) using btree,
key idx_student_name(name) using btree,
key idx_student_age(age) using btree
)
```

then

```
explain select * from student s where name like 'ron%' and age > 10
```

the result shows below
[image: explain result]

googled a alot but still confused why mysql can using index condition for two sinle column index? anyone can help me understand it? many thanks!

Comment: in my mind, index condition pushdown only works in composite indexes (that is, indexes on multiple columns)

Comment: I don't understand your question and what is "sinle"? Is it a typo?.. of "single"?

Comment: EXPLAIN tells that there exists 2 indices-candidates for to be used, and that only one of them (idx_student_name) is used.

Comment: A lot of typos in the question, makes it unclear. Just add what are you trying to achieve here.